# Python, code doing the first thing then looping to the end

Tags: python

I am making a small quiz and trying to learn python. The quiz takes the first answer then loops all the way to the bottom instead of asking the user the rest of the questions. It will print the first question, then ask for the answer , then it will run throught the rest of the code but it won't actually ask for the input or anything like that.

```
question_1 = ("ex1") 
question_2 = ("ex2") 
question_3 = ("ex3") 
question_4 = ("ex4") 
answer = input ("Please type the letter you think is correct: ")
count = 0
# answers 
print (question_1)
print ("A. ")
print ("B. ")
print ("C. ")
print ("D. ")
if answer == "b" or answer == "B":
    print ("Correct")
    count +=1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
print (question_2)
print ("A. ")
print ("B. ")
print ("C. ")
print ("D. ")
if answer == "a" or answer == "A":
    print ("Correct")
    count +=1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
print (question_3)
print ("A. ")
print ("B. ")
print ("C. ")
print ("D. ")
if answer == "d" or answer == "D":
    print ("Correct")
    count +=1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
print (question_4)
print ("A. ")
print ("B. ")
print ("C. ")
print ("D. ")
if answer == "c" or answer == "C":
    print ("Correct")
    count +=1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You have to read input after each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only asking for one input and then checking that answer against every question.

You will need to add a new input for every question and then check against that input

e.g.

```py
count = 0
print('Q1')
ans1 = input('A/B/C?')

if ans1.lower() == 'c': # Checks for it as a lowercase so no need to repeat it
  print('Correct')
  count += 1
else:
  print('Incorrect')

print('Q2')
ans2 = input('A/B/C?')

if ans2.lower() == 'b':
  print('Correct')
  count += 1
else:
  print('Incorrect')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the input() function after each question. An input is asked for at each input, writing it once before all the questions won't work.

By the way, you might want to use lists and a loop to get the same done with less code.